# Powershell Validate Range Parameter Error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script that automates Windows USMT backups but I am running into an issue with Powershell 2.0.  Basically I have a script parameter that requires a positive integer and the validation works in Powershell 3.0+ but not in 2.0, which ships in Windows 7.

Parameter Code:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [ValidateScript({
        if( -Not ($_ | Test-Path) ){
            throw "File or folder does not exist"
        }
        if($_ | Test-Path -PathType Leaf){
            throw "The Path argument must be a folder. file paths are not allowed."
        }
        if( -not (($_ | Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) ) {
            throw "The Folder '$_' Has Content/Files! USMT will not run against a non-empty backup folder!!"
        }
        return $true
    })]
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$BackupPath,

    [switch]$OfflineUSBDock,

    [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)][int]$UEL
)
```

The Error: [image]

So my question is how do I fix this to work correctly in Powershell 2.0?  The goal is for the $UEL parameter to only accept a positive Integer.

[Full Script](https://pastebin.com/va289JTn)

Comment: If your goal is only a positive integer, use the `[uint32]` (unsigned) type.

Comment: This would work but it needs to be at least 1; uint32 has a min of 0.  Though at this point I could probably just use a ValidateScript.

Comment: Try wrapping your constant in parenthesis: `[ValidateRange(1, ([int]::MaxValue))]`  This should force it to be evaluated

Comment: no dice!  It throws the same error.  It can evaluate [int]::MaxValue elsewhere in the script or, just at the prompt, but for some reason it just doesn't like it in the validation.

Comment: It looks like you will need to hardcode the `MaxValue` constant (`2147483647`) into the second parameter of the validation then.

Answer (score 2):

Here 2 workarounds from the comments (thanks @TheIncorrigible for the 
recommendations):

```
[ValidateScript({
    if ($_ -eq 0) {
        throw "UEL requires a positive integer greater then 0!"
    }
    return $true
})]    
[uint32]$UEL
```

or

```
 [ValidateRange(1, 2147483647)][int]$UEL
```

Not as clean as using `[int]::MaxValue` but it gets the job done.